# Cannot add apps neither extensions to Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Chrome web browser crashed while running the app Secure Shell, so I cannot add apps neither extensions to Chrome anymore, and my old apps and extensions disappeared.

How to fix this ? When I try to add apps I receive the error: "An error has occurred, NETWORK_FAILED":

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome re-installation (uninstall + install) fixed it.  Nothing changed in my google account, all apps previously installed was restored, including Secure Shell app.